# Как сделать такое горизонтальное меню

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Всем привет, вот практикую свои знания в web-дизайне, и тут возникло препятствие, которое я не могу реализовать сам, и поэтому прошу вашей помощи в этом.

[image]

Я бы хотел сделать такое-же меню, но когда я делаю по урокам которые нахожу в инете, то у меня получается такая бяка:

[image]

Что на скриншоте...
1) Пустота непонятно откуда взялась, и почему-то блоки уже не "растягивают" тело страницы, а выходят за его пределы.

Помогите исправить.

Исходный код html и css вы можете найти здесь:
[Ссылка](http://angus123.24-hoster.ru/)

Comment: В общем ни каких лишних пустот я не увидел - прилагаю скрин ![введите сюда описание изображения](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4jfMm.png)! а вообще такое меню вкрутить дело 15 минут

Comment: @Keeplod, вопрос 2012 года.

Comment: @meine а зачем вы пинаете комментарий 15 ого года?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том что по высоте 100% не обновляеться размер блока #left.
С помощью js  можно установить нужное значение динамечески.